# Wrong badges color in dark mode

Tags: bug, design, dark-mode

As far as I can remember, there has been no problem here. But I just logged in today and noticed this issue.
Note that the color when you hover the button with your mouse stays in a normal dark color.

Maybe that's because I am using Opera? There has been an update recently.

[image]